# How to disable input translation for some keys in GNU Screen?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I have `Ctrl-Left` and `Ctrl-Right` bound for vim, and would like to be able to use these shortcuts when vim runs inside screen.

However, because of Screen's [input translation](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_10.html#SEC50) my key presses are mangled and vim does the wrong thing.

Trying to disable the key bindings with `bindkey kr` or `bindkey -k kr` while under screen does not work.

How do I keep my vim shortcuts while running it under screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the $TERM variable to something that supports those keys. By default screen sets it to 'screen'. I have found setting it to 'xterm' does the trick. To achieve this you have two options.

Start screen like this: `screen -T xterm`, or put the following in your .screenrc.

```
term    xterm
```