# Scrolling in Vim through Screen (and PuTTY) sometimes inserts random characters

Tags: vim, putty, gnu-screen

I'm having a strange problem with Vim, screen and putty.

I am connecting to Screen through Putty, which, in general, works fine. I have had some issues with getting scrolling to work in Vim, however.

Some details:

- I set `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@` in my screenrc so that I can use the mousewheel to scroll. It doesn't work great (scrollback gets muddled between screen windows), but I prefer it to using the keyboard
- I have `set term=xterm` in my vimrc.
- Also in my vimrc, I have set `mouse=a` and `ttymouse=xterm2`, so that I can use the mousewheel. This is where problems arise

  - When I scroll with the mouse in the left side of the PuTTY window, it works fine
  - When I scroll with the mouse in the right side of the PuTTY window, random characters either get inserted into the file I'm editing, or into the Vim command line.

I can't find anyone else with this problem when I've searched, and I'm at a loss for things to try.  Any suggestions as to what I could try would be really useful.

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Are the strange characters gone when you type `ctrl-L` (redraw screen)?

Comment: No, they remain - they also get saved to disk if I save the file.

Comment: I believe this question could be considered a duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/343203/how-to-disable-input-translation-for-some-keys-in-gnu-screen/349303#349303).

Comment: Hey @AdamTonks, having the same issue, any resolution?

Comment: @Horak Sorry - don't think I ever got this fixed.  Ended up going a different direction, and using tmux rather than screen.

Answer (score 1):

Putting "`set term=xterm`" in your vimrc is a bad idea, and probably the cause of your problems; when running under screen, your TERM (on the shell) and the `'term'` option in Vim should be "screen" and nothing else.

If you were trying to solve a problem with TERM by setting the `'term'` option in Vim, you need to find the actual source of the problem and fix it there.  Is PuTTY emulating the right terminal type? Is your shell *before* you start screen reflecting the proper TERM? (`echo $TERM` on the shell command-line).  And, finally, is your shell *after*  you start screen set to "screen" (as it always should be)?

If you still have this problem after you've corrected the TERM issues, check the output of:

```
:verbose set ttimeout? ttimeoutlen?
```

(Note the double t's, and the question marks are part of the command.)

Normally the output would be "nottimeout ttimeoutlen=-1" on two lines, if they're anything else, try resetting them:

```
:set ttimeout& ttimeoutlen&
```

Comment: I guess I should say that _unconditionally_ setting 'term' in your vimrc is a bad idea. I personally set 'term' to xterm-256color if my 'term' is "xterm" and $COLORTERM in my environment is "gnome-terminal".